# Loading a custom .dll in DM 3.4

Tags: dll, dm-script

I have just installed DM 3.4 and am generally quite satisfied. Though, I have one issue concerning a custom .dll which causes the warning

> #### "You have incompatible plug-ins on your system. Do you want to load these potentially harmful plug-ins?"

If I press yes everything works normally and I trust the author of the .dll hence I'd like to suppress this warning.

Is there anything like an ignore list in which one can force to load the .dll straight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't, and it is there for a good reason. Regardless of your trust to the other author, the used DLL was not compiled with the correct version of the SDK. As a result, even the most tested and well written code can produce completely unexpected random crashes.

The warning is there to make you aware of this and don't report "bugs" of GMS which aren't any.

If the 3rd party DLL is important to you, please contact the original author and request that he rebuilds the DLL with the required version of the SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have requested the latest SDK and will compile a new version.